# reading data from firebase as cache

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, caching

I have many documents in my project. I always divided them into separate collections. My question is this. I want to read the collection at the bottom of a document in a collection. When doing this, does firebase read every document in the first collection? This increases my cost. I am sharing screenshots for better understanding. For example, in this collection, I am getting all documents in document 16. While doing this, does firebase unnecessarily read other numbered documents and the documents in them? Also, I have a code. According to this code, do I read only the documents in that document?

Also, my other question is. I don't want to read them over firebase every time. For example, after receiving the document number 16, I want to retrieve it from the cache. Is there a way to do this? Continuously pulling the same data from the firebase increases the cost and the number of reads? Or is there another method? What would be the easiest way to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMx43.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XUFI.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.